# Incorrect syntax for Union All query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine to queries with union all:

```
use SalesDWH
go


select cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar) +'|'+[practice name]+'|'+b.[mlis practice id]+'|'+[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+c.salesrep+'|'+
    cast(c.dateestablished as varchar)+'|'+ c.practicecity+'|'+c.practicestate
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) = 2011
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12
group by a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate
order by COUNT([specimen id]) desc

union all

select cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar) +'|'+[practice name]+'|'+b.[mlis practice id]+'|'+[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+c.salesrep+'|'+
    cast(c.dateestablished as varchar)+'|'+ c.practicecity+'|'+c.practicestate
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) = 2011
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11
group by a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate
order by COUNT([specimen id]) desc
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the first

```
order by COUNT([specimen id]) desc
```

or do this:

```
select cDATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) as Month, cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar) +'|'+[practice name]+'|'+b.[mlis practice id]+'|'+[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+c.salesrep+'|'+
    cast(c.dateestablished as varchar)+'|'+ c.practicecity+'|'+c.practicestate
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) = 2011
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) in (11,12)
group by DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]), a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate
order by COUNT([specimen id]) desc
```

You can also say something like

```
select CASE WHEN cDATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11 THEN 'The 11th Month' 
           WHEN cDATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12 THEN 'The 12th Month' END as [when], ...
```

Comment: thanks so much. if i were to do it this way (11,12)... i would want to differentiate between the data in 11 and the data in 12, how would i do that? can you show me how i can do a CASE statement and add an extra output column that would say 11 or 12?

Comment: It is in the group by.  I'll add the column.

Comment: and just out of curiosity, can you please me why it did not work with UNION ALL when i followed your and eric's advice on putting that ORDER BY only at the last line?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Answer (score 11):

Your `order by` can only go on the last statement:

```
use SalesDWH
go


select cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar) +'|'+[practice name]+'|'+b.[mlis practice id]+'|'+[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+c.salesrep+'|'+
    cast(c.dateestablished as varchar)+'|'+ c.practicecity+'|'+c.practicestate
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) = 2011
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12
group by a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate

union all

select cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar) +'|'+[practice name]+'|'+b.[mlis practice id]+'|'+[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+c.salesrep+'|'+
    cast(c.dateestablished as varchar)+'|'+ c.practicecity+'|'+c.practicestate
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) = 2011
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11
group by a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate
order by COUNT([specimen id]) desc
```

This is because the ordering happens after the result set is attained, which is post union. You can't order a set before it finally returns.

Comment: thanks so much. just tried this and got Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.